# Harmonic interpolation with analytic initial condition

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, harmonic-analysis, potential-theory, interpolation, harmonic-functions

Let $n>1$ and  $M\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a (sufficiently low dimensional)  compact  analytic submanifold.

Assume that $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ is an analytic function.

Is there a Harmonic function $u:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ with $u\biggm|_M=f\biggm|_M$?

Comment: The submanifold itself must be analytic.

Comment: Yes Thank you. I edit it. However it was implicitly included in the question.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Could you elaborate on this - why need $M$ be analytic?

Comment: @LeoMoos  for this alternative(possible equivalent) formulation: Let $f:M\to \mathbb{R}$ be a real analytic function then is there a harmonic function on R^n which restrict to f? the reason we consider the real analyticity is that by regularity theorems every Harmonic function is real analytic.

Comment: @LeoMoos  ....For this alternative (but not necessarily equivalent)  formulation... anyway lets tak the best case in the analytic world. So I keep the formulation of the posted question. The initial condition comes from an analytic function on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Just a quick observation: if you do not require any special behavior to $u$ at infinity, it may exist but it is surely not unique. I am aying this since your problem seems related to the Cauchy problem for a harmonic function: in such case, if you do not specify the normal derivative $\left.\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}\right|_{M}$, perhaps by putting $$\left.\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}\right|_{M}=\left.\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \nu}\right|_{M},$$ you have an underdetermined problem.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri  thank you for your comment. In the question we do not require $M$ to be codimension 1. For example $M$ is a knot in space. Is there an immediate solution?However your comment indicate me that we have a huge number of solution, it would be  underdetermined problem.

Comment: You have exactly spotted the core of the problem: depending not only on the structure of $M$ (dimension, smoothness,... etc.) but also on the boundary conditions specified on it, you may have a huge "number" (possibly as many as a vector subspace) of solutions.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri  If we reduce the manifold condition to a compact subset but with very low dimension(Topologic or Hausddorf) one encounter some new questions. For example let $K$ be a Cantor set in space. is there a counter example of an analytic function $F:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}$ which is not equale to a harmonic function $u:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ when we restrict both functions to $K$?

Answer (score 1):

The following cannot be considered a satisfactory answer since it does not provide a construction of the sought for harmonic function $u$: however, it provides a possible path for its construction. In my comments above I was perhaps fooled by the fact that I usually deal with boundary value problems, so I tried to see if the problem posed was reducible to a Cauchy problem. However, having thought a bit of it, it seems to me that the best approach to this specific case is by using approximation theory, precisely the following theorem, which is a particular case of a result proved by Stephen Gardiner (see [1], §1.10, pp. 23-24):

**Theorem**. Let $\Omega\subseteq\mathbf{R}^n$ an open set and $M$ be a compact subset of $\Omega$ whose interior is empty. The following statement are equivalent

1. for each $f\in C(M)$ and each positive number $\epsilon$, there exists a function $u$ harmonic in $\Omega$ such that $|u-f|<\epsilon$ on $M$;
2. $\Omega\setminus \hat{M}$ is a thin set (in the sense of potential theory, see for example [1], §0.2, p. 2) in the same points of $M$, where  $\hat{M}$ is the *union of all* $\Omega$-*bounded components of* $\Omega\setminus M$ (see [1], §1.7, p. 18 for the precise definitions)

**Notes**

- The above theorem is less general than the one proved by Gardiner since I have assumed that $M$ has an empty interior, due to the hypothesis of low dimensionality: the result is true even if it is not so. In that case we have $u\in C(M)\cap\mathscr{H}(\overset{\circ}{M})$ and we need also $\Omega\setminus\overset{\circ}{M}$ to be thin in the same point as $M$: here $\overset{\circ}{M}$ is the interior of $M$ while $\mathscr{H}({A})$ is the set of all harmonic functions on the domain $A$.
- As said above this answer cannot be considered complete since I've not provided an explicit way to construct the sought for harmonic function $u$, possibly as a limit of an appropriate sequences of (likewise) harmonic functions when $f$ is real analytic on $M$. However, I'll try to see how this can be done.

**References**

[1] Stephen J. Gardiner, *[Harmonic approximation](https://books.google.it/books?id=FyfQGjs9DPQC&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PP1&dq=Gardiner%2C%20Stephen%20%22Harmonic%20approximation%22&hl=it&pg=PR4#v=onepage&q&f=false)* (English),
London Mathematical Society Lecture Note Series, 221, Cambridge: Cambridge University Press, pp. xiii+132 (1995), ISBN: 0-521-49799-X, [MR1342298](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR1342298) [Zbl 0826.31002](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0826.31002).

[2] Peter Henrici, *Applied and computational complex analysis. Volume I: Power series- integration-conformal mapping-location of zeros*, reprint of the original, published in 1974 by John Wiley & Sons Ltd., Paperback ed. (English) Wiley Classics Library. New York etc.: John Wiley & Sons Ltd. xv, 682 p. $ 25.95 (1988), ISBN: 0-471-60841-6, [MR1008928](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR1008928), [Zbl 0635.30001](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0635.30001)

Comment: Thank you very much for your informative and interesting answer.